# ajax success function not fired MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to get my success result in a div through ajax query.

Ajax query is taking `model` value as parameter and filtering result according to that.

**Here is my ajax query and view page-**

```
@model IEnumerable<FunRanger.Models.TagModel>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#' + '@item.tagId').click(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Tag/TagFilter/?tagName=' + '@item.tagName',
                    type: 'post',
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#funhome-partial').html(data);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
    <div class="tags">
        <a href="#" id="@item.tagId">#@item.tagName</a>
    </div>

}
```

I am trying to filter this result in another div whose id is 'funhome-partial`. This div is in **Another project file** of my project.

**Action-**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TagFilter(TagModel tag) {
    var cardlist = (from u in db.CardTables
                    where u.CardHashCode.Contains(tag.tagName)
                    select new CardModel {
                        cardHashCode = tag.tagName,
                        cardDate = u.CardDate,
                        cardFileName = u.CardFileName,
                        cardFilePath = u.CardFilePath,
                        cardID = u.CardID,
                        cardTitle = u.CardTitle
                    }).ToList();
    return View("FunHome", cardlist);

}
```

Everything works fine. I get filtered records according to that parameter that i can check by putting breakpoint there.

But This query doesn't call `success` function of ajax and shows me this error-

In case of a parameter named `RipEnglish`.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) http://localhost:61203/Tag/TagFilter/?tagName=RipEnglish
```

How do I get ajax success result called, also is this a fine way of doing it?

Comment: http500 is an error. You wont get a success result because its not a success.

Comment: Not sure if this is causing the problem but shouldn't your queryString be `?tag=` not `?tagName=`

Comment: @Jamiec, You are right It is not going to success. But I can't track error. whether action retrieves filtered result.

Comment: Add an `error` callback to your ajax call. Then you will be able to track the error (or, just set a breakpoint in your server code and debug it)

Comment: @talegna, I suppose no. Because I am parsing this through model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed this issue working.

It was so simple to track after @gooberverse's answer.

I checked in developer tools>network>response and it said me `no view engine supports the searched locations or not found in searched locations` error.

Though I had to create a shared view-->  `shared>_SharedView` and had to render it with the same method.

And it worked like charm.

Answer (score 3):

AJAX can be difficult to troubleshoot if you don't have a lot of experience with it. The Developer Tools (or FireBug) available for all modern browsers are your friend. They make it much easier to see/understand what the server is returning as a response.

Since the request is using Ajax, the browser won't render any error pages that are returned.

Using Chrome (the other tools are similar and usually opened with CTRL + SHIFT + I or F12):

1. **Open the Developer Tools** pane with (CTRL + SHIFT + I).
2. Click the **Network** tab.
3. Click your page element to fire the click handler and send the Ajax request.
4. Find and **click** the network request in the **Network** tab (bottom-left).
5. The pane next to the network request has Tabs for '**Headers**', '**Preview**' and '**Response**'.

**Headers** will show you the contents of the request (what got sent to the server).

**Response** will show you the content of the servers response. This might be JSON for a successful request or it might be HTML source for an error page if an error occured.

The **Preview** tab will render the servers Response (if possible). This is especially helpful if you receive an error response/page from the server since you won't have to wade through the raw HTML to find the error details.

If your AJAX call is failing, and your server returns a 500 error, you can always check your server logs or look at the Network > Preview tab to see the error detail that is returned. You can troubleshoot the error just as you would any traditional server response.

Answer (score 0):

I reconstructed your scenario and then solution goes this way, you need to check out your jquery click function.

Sample model which I used -

```
public class Tag
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller Actions -

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult SubmitTag(Tag t)
    {
        return new ContentResult() { Content = t.TagName + "1" };
    }
```

Index View with JQuery -

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#ClickMe").click(function () {

            var tag = {
                "TagName": "SampleTag"
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("SubmitTag")",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(tag),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#funhome').html(data);
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText + "e");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>

<input type="button" id="ClickMe" value="ClickMe" />
<div id="funhome"></div>
```

And finally the output -

[image]

At debugging -

[image]